# Aurelia or Webpack is not binding the images on time

Tags: image, webpack, aurelia

from the API i get results for the images i need to show on my VIEW (html page). I get the id's of the images and i have also api which returns the image from the given id.

in my .ts of the component i get the ids for the images i need to show and put them in list on the following way:

```
async attached(){
for(var i = 0; i<this.searchResults.length;i++){
let image = this.searchResults[i].carImage;
let response = await this.api.get(`/images/${image}`);
this.carImages.push(response);
}}
```

then in my .html file of the component i do the following

```
<div class="col-4" repeat.for="result of searchResults">
            <div class="card" >
              <img class="card-img-top" src="${carProfilePicture(result.carImage)}" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="float-right card-price" style="text-align:center">
        <span><span style="font-weight:bold;">$ ${result.price}</span> /day</span>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${result.make} ${result.model} - ${result.year}</h5>
                <label class="card-text">20+ trips - <span style="border: 1px solid black;"> ${result.carClass}
                    class </span></label>
                <p><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i></p>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" click.trigger="navigateToCar()">Continue <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

then i also have 1 more function that returns the car picture for every element

```
async carProfilePicture(imageId) {
    let response = await this.api.get(`/images/${imageId}`);
    return response;
  }
```

but pictures are not shown in my html so i dont know what is the problem and what is the next step i need to try. Thank you very much

Comment: Why can't you just let the browser directly load the images? `<img  src="/images/${result.carImage}" />`

Comment: If that isn't possible, then you'll need to rework your code. Aurelia assumes any functions you call in your view are "pure functons." The output of a pure function only changes if the input changes. So unless `result.careImage` changes, Aurelia won't call the `carProfilePicture` function.

Comment: When i directly load on the first comment as you say everything works fine. Thank you very much @AshleyGrant . I thought a function needs to work because everytime result is changing so i thought that the function is called too, because `result.careImage` is changing everytime